# Custom Search Visualforce page with two columns

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a very simple search page that I want to display the data in the two column
but I'm unable to do unless if I have `apex:pageblockTable` is that possible to do without pageblocktable?

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="RetUrlSearchController">
  <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
      <apex:pageBlockSection title="Criteria">
      <apex:outputLabel value="Enter Name Snippet"/>
      <apex:inputText value="{!nameQuery}"/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!executeSearch}" value="Search"/>
   </apex:pageBlockSection>

   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
      <apex:column headerValue="Name">
         <apex:outputLink value="/{!acc.id}/e?retURL={!URLENCODE('/apex/RetUrlSearchPage?query='+nameQuery)}">{!acc.Name}</apex:outputLink>
      </apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!acc.BillingStreet}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
 </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public class RetUrlSearchController 
{
 public String nameQuery {get; set;}
 public List<Account> accounts {get; set;}

 public PageReference executeSearch()
 {
  String queryStr='%' + nameQuery + '%';
  accounts=[select id, Name, BillingStreet 
            from Account 
            where name like :queryStr];

  return null;
 }

 public RetUrlSearchController()
 {
  // if query appears in URL, execute it
  String urlQuery=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('query');

  if ( (null!=urlQuery) && (0!=urlQuery.length()) )
  {
   nameQuery=urlQuery;
   executeSearch();
  }
 }
}
```

Here is what I want the format to be:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information" columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!accounts.Id}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!accounts.Name}"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!accounts.BillingStreet}"/>

        .......... 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

the error i'm getting if i use that in above format:

> Error: Could not resolve the entity from  value
>   binding '{!accounts.id}'.

Comment: So what's wrong with using `columns="2"`?

Comment: its not rendering, if i use the `<apex:pageBlockSection title="General Information" columns="2">` let me update my question with the error message i'm getting

Comment: all what i have seen the sample code is used `apex:pageBlockTable` but in my case i do not want to use `apex:pageBlockTable`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just like with `pageBlockTable`, you need to iterate over the collection. When you do:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
    ...
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

You create a local variable inside of that tag named `acc`. The `accounts` property is just a list and doesn't have any properties like `id`. The `acc` records have those properties, so to create that reference you can instead do an `apex:repeat`.

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:repeat value="{!accounts}" var="acc">
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.Edit, acc.id, [retURL=URLENCODE('/apex/RetUrlSearchPage?query='+nameQuery)}">
                {!acc.Name}
            </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:outputField value="{!acc.BillingStreet}" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: awesome as always :) 1+